# Need to change the category url in magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to change the Category url. I am updating the url in Search Engine Optimization. 
URL is `/brickwebb.html` but need to change `shop/brickwebb.html`. 
This is not updating and getting `shop-brickwebb.html`.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: see this it might help https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Categrory-URL-Rewrite-Not-Working-After-Upgrading-To-Magento-2-3/m-p/129125#M1949

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prepend **shop** for all your categories, then you can create your custom module and create a router for the same to forward it to appropriate category.

If you want individual slug for each category then you can create a custom attribute for that category and write conditions in custom router to forward it.